# filter data in R shiny using predefined variables where some of them could be empty or NA?

Tags: r, shiny

i am trying to build an application with R shiny where i can load that famous data "mpg" and then filter it using a loaded data which is in fact a loaded excel having as column names some of the column names of the mpg data .One of this excel files looks like this:manufacturer, model,      displ,  year as column names and as values for these columns we have the following:audi,"",          1.8,  1999.the second column has empty value or NA .The code below show how to load that excel files and used to filter the data and then plot something.It is meant by that emtpy value is to choose everythig in the mpg data ,in other words not to  filter anything residing in the "model" column:

```
  newdata<-list()
      
   newdata<-readxl::read_excel(paste0(getwd(),"/","myfolder","/","setting.xlsx"))
       
      dat<- mpg 
      dt<-dat[dat$manufacturer==newdata$manufacturer & dat$model==newdata$model& dat$displ=newdata$displ& dat$year==newdata$year,]

ggplot(dt,aes(displ,cty))+
geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to check for "equal to" i.e `==` and your `newdata` only has one value pr column then a for loop will work.

```
df <- mpg

# I do not have access to your data, 
# but the functionality is the same with a list
newdata <- list( 
  manufacturer = "audi",
  model = "a4 quattro",
  displ = NA
)

for(f in names(newdata)){
  if(!is.na(newdata[[f]]))
    df <- df[df[[f]] == newdata[[f]],]
}
```

For each name in the `newdata` data.frame, the loop chunk is run with `f` as the name. The `df[df[[f]] == newdata[[f]],]` then compares each column, but only if `newdata[[f]]` is not `NA`.

Of course, a problem will arise if your `newdata` has columns that are not in the `mpg` data. Here an additional condition can be made such as `if(!is.na(newdata[[f]]) & f %in% df)`

Comment: Thank you bro! from the bottom of my heart .iwas stucked there since days.Now my question is that newdata is a list of data frame as follows:    
   
dx<-data.frame(manufacturer = "audi",
               model = "a4 quattro",
               displ = NA)
dy<-data.frame(manufacturer = "audi",
               model = "a4",
               displ = NA)
newdata <- list( dx,dy) .Now i want to run that list filter every time and plot everytime.Just show how to filter using newdata[[i]]

Comment: This could be done with a nested for loop. I cannot comment the whole answer, but the whole loop would then look something like: `for(df in newdata){for(f in names(df)){*FILTER CODE HERE*}}`

Comment: Although, there are different ways of filtering when you have many values, such as using `%in%`. So you could bind the dataframes together with `rbind()` and then use the loop in the answer only changing the `==` operator with `%in%` operator. You could also check out some libraries for this, such as `dplyr`

Comment: could you please edit your solution and help me because i have just tried the ensted lopp and it does give one plot and the second plot is empty.

Comment: df <- mpg

dx<-data.frame(manufacturer = "audi",
               model = "a4 quattro",
               displ = NA)
dy<-data.frame(manufacturer = "audi",
               model = "a4",
               displ = NA)
newdata <- list( dx,dy)

for (i in 1:2){
for(f in names(newdata[[i]])){
  if(!is.na(newdata[[i]][[f]]))
    df <- df[df[[f]] == newdata[[i]][[f]],]
  
}
  p<- ggplot(df,aes(displ,cty))+
    geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)
  print(p)
 
 

}
 can you please try to run this?